# How to create a admin-editable list in django or by using Python?

Tags: python, django

any suggestions on this? I get an syntax error with this? Any alternative that I can try to get Admin-editable list work ? Thank you, Rads

```
<a href="#" id="amenities" data-type="checklist" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-  title="Select amenities"></a>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#amenities').editable({
        value: [2, 3, 4],
        source: [
            {value: 1, text: 'Internet'},
            {value: 2, text: 'Full Kitchen'},
            {value: 3, text: 'Big screen TV'}
            {value: 4, text: 'Business Center'}
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am sorry Weasel. I have posted the Traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is that you're missing a comma at the end of:

```
{value: 3, text: 'Big screen TV'}
```

Try adding one and see what happens?

Comment: Hi Augier, Thank you for the suggestion. I tried still stuck with the same error. Any suggestions on it? Thank you, Rads

Comment: Rads, is that enclosed as a string literal? Can you edit your post to add the whole model?

Comment: from django.db import models    class Room(models.Model):  rentAmount = models.IntegerField()<a href="#" id="amenities" data-type="checklist" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Select amenities"></a>
 <script>
 $(function(){
  $('#amenities').editable({
   value: [2, 3, 4],
   source: [
    {value: 1, text: 'Internet'},
    {value: 2, text: 'Full Kitchen'},
    {value: 3, text: 'Big screen TV'},
    {value: 4, text: 'Business Center'}
   ]
  });
 });
 </script>

Comment: Here is the link I followed to create the checklist data type. http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html

Comment: I can't understand why there is HTML and Javascript in your models file. This should be in your templates, or if you are defining custom widget to use on forms, use this guide https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: Thank you for the link Augier